# Ubuntu New version

Tags: 12.04, server, upgrade, 14.04, compatibility

So, I have managed to use ubuntu for 6 months or so, and I have completely ignored the Zorin distro. Using a youtube video I managed to install ubuntu server 12.04 and I have been very happy with everything.

I noticed that ubuntu 14 is out and I am downloading it, but Ubutu server 14 is only available in 64 bit.

So my question is if I install ubuntu 14.04 desktop will ubuntu 12.04 server still work fine?

I am imagining that this is a silly question but I would like to check before I do anything too erratic.

Comment: Both should work, if you do it right.

Answer (score 0):

open up a terminal and type the following

```
uname -p
```

if the result is

```
x86_64
```

you are fine, and can download the 64-bit release

if your result is

```
i386
```

you'll have to go to

```
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads
```

and download the torrent

```
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server (32-bit)
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip. Whenever I type uname -p I get i686 (I had to look twice). I have a Dell XPS 400 supposedly 64bit but I have tried 14.04 and I had a lot of problems with both versions. 32/64 So, until things get more stable, I am reverting back to 12.04 LTS .

Comment: There also is `uname -i`. It is similar, but I don't know the difference between the `-i` and `-p`, but most of the time (I think), they give the same result. `i686` and `i386` [and a few others with similar names] means 32-bit. Glad to help.